# Ipod Classic not recognized by iTunes (Windows 8.1)

Tags: itunes, windows, ipod, ipod-classic

I have an 80GB iPod classic that is not being recognized by iTunes.  Here's what happened:

- Ipod ran out of battery. I charged it on a speaker dock, and it opened with no memory, restored to default settings (no idea why)
- I tried to connect it to itunes, and it didn't work.  My computer recognizes it as a removable drive and it indicated it was charging but itunes did not recognize a device was connected.
- I uninstalled and re-installed itunes (no change)
- I put the ipod in disk mode and connected it (no change)
- I ran an diagnostic in itunes, and theses were the results:

---

```
Microsoft Windows 8 x64 Home Premium Edition (Build 9200)
Dell Inc. Inspiron 3521
iTunes 12.2.0.145
QuickTime not available
FairPlay 2.8.28
Apple Application Support 3.2
iPod Updater Library 12.0
CD Driver 2.2.3.0
CD Driver DLL 2.1.3.1
Apple Mobile Device 8.2.1.3
Apple Mobile Device Driver 1.67.0.0
Bonjour 3.0.0.10 (333.10)
Gracenote SDK 3.06.1.3084
Gracenote MusicID 3.06.1.3084
Gracenote Submit 3.06.1.3084
Gracenote DSP 3.06.1.3084

iTunes Serial Number 000000897B7B8E7C

Current user is not an administrator.
The current local date and time is 2015-07-05 18:27:22.
iTunes is not running in safe mode.
WebKit accelerated compositing is enabled.
HDCP is supported.
Core Media is supported.


**** External Plug-ins Information ****

No external plug-ins installed.

**** Device Connectivity Tests ****

iPodService 12.2.0.145 (x64) is currently running.
iTunesHelper 12.2.0.145 is currently running.
Apple Mobile Device Service service 3.3.0.0 is currently running.

No Universal Serial Bus Controller found.

No FireWire (IEEE 1394) Host Controller found.

Most Recent Devices Not Currently Connected:

iPod classic running firmware version 1.1.2
Serial Number:  8!@#$%^&*()
```

Note: It gave the real serial number, not sure if i should post it with that though.

Other things:
My computer is a Dell, running windows 8.1; I have connected this ipod to this computer and updated it successfully before.  There is no damage to the cord, or USB ports.  I do not have access to another computer to test the ipod.

Thanks in advance for any advice as to how to proceed, I really want to be able to use my ipod again!

Comment: what does the windows say to that device ?

Comment: It looks like it is running the iPodService 12.2.0.145

Answer (score 1):

That is a know problem.

Choices are to go back to iTunes 11 or try to fix the iPOD.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6807069